# Parse a YAML like file to CSV

Tags: python

I have a txt file with YAML like syntax. Below is a sample from that. its not fully yaml because there is no colon after DOC ID.

```
Event Data is :
  ID Of Event : {F0B0E47E-0000-CE23-B591-88522468FD33}
  Name OF Event : UpdateEvent
  Date Created: Thu Feb 10 23:01:50 IST 2022
  Event Status: Succeeded
  Event SeqNumber: 3.0
  DOC Id           {80A5E47E-0000-CB1F-BEE6-2402455A10AE}
Source modified object: 
   Name: sssssssss
   Date object modified: Thu Feb 10 23:01:50 IST 2022

 
Event Data is :
  ID Of Event : {F0B0E47E-0000-CE23-B591-88522468FD33}
  Name OF Event : UpdateEvent
  Date Created: Thu Feb 10 23:01:50 IST 2022
  Event Status: Succeeded
  Event SeqNumber: 3.0
  DOC Id           {80A5E47E-0000-CB1F-BEE6-2402455A2AE}
Source modified object: 
   Name: sssssssss
   Date object modified: Thu Feb 10 23:01:50 IST 2022
```

I need to parse this file and create a CSV file in the below formate

```
ID Of Event,Name OF Event,Date Created,Event Status,Event SeqNumber,DOC Id ,Source modified object:
F0B0E47E-0000-CE23-B591-88522468FD33,UpdateEvent,Thu Feb 10 23:01:50 IST 2022,Succeeded,3,80A5E47E-0000-CB1F-BEE6-2402455A2AE,"Name: sssssssss, Date object modified: Thu Feb 10 23:01:50 IST 2022"
F0B0E47E-0000-CE23-B591-88522468FD33,UpdateEvent,Thu Feb 10 23:01:50 IST 2022,Succeeded,3,80A5E47E-0000-CB1F-BEE6-2402455A2AE,"Name: sssssssss, Date object modified: Thu Feb 10 23:01:50 IST 2022"
```

I tried with pyyaml it doesnt work because its not in proper yaml formate. any other options?

Comment: What would happen if you inserted a colon after the "DOC Id"? If that would then make it parse-able by PyYAML does that solve your problem?

Comment: yes, it would resolve the issue. but the problem is that file is getting generated by a legacy system which at the moment we cannot change.

Comment: `input.replace("DOC Id", "DOC Id:")` ?